# Is it safe to power Raspberry Pi 4 with 8V?

Tags: power-supply, safety

I have a ESC control from an RC car similar to this one:

[image: one]

and although it says it has a UBEC of 6V, I measure 8V when I supply the ESC with two 18650 batteries in series.

I want to supply my Raspi 4 with the UBEC (from the 3-pin head). Will it be safe?

Comment: If memory serves, the recommended Pi supply voltage is 4.75 to 5.25V, the absolute maximum is 5.45V.

Comment: yes, but only once and then only for a couple milliseconds at most. Just the time it needs to burn something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pi data states 5±0.25V; the MxL7704 PMIC Data states Input voltage range: 4.0V to 5.5V so **NO**

If your 6V UBEC is producing 8V I would throw it in the bin!